# How to update single record in mongodb from node.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am using mongo db on nodejs. I am trying to update record by unique key. When I prepare arguments pro grammatically, getting failed. If I hard coded the set params, working fine.

How to create $set parameters in run time on node.js server.

code:

```
var collection = db.collection('test', function(err, collection) {

 var args = "{field1: 5}";

 collection.update({unique_key_field: val}, {$set: args}, w:1, function(e, r) {

  //always failed.
  // If I copy {field1: 5} at args place, it's updating properly.

 });;
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`args` needs to be an actual object, not a stringified object:

```
var args = { field1: 5 };
```

Comment: How to send multiple arguments to $set? any idea?